# Switched to promise based DB, now my login is completely broken

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-development-server

I can register just fine, however when I get directed to my game route I get a default Error page that's just white with `[object Object]` on the screen. Then I get the same in my console, `[object Object]` and it repeats every once in a while.

At first I thought it was something to do with socket.io, but it isn't even getting to that point. I think it might be something with passport and how I have it configured, not being setup good with the promise route I'm going, but I am at a complete loss. I don't know exactly where this error is occurring.

Here is the passport file:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const db = require('../config/db');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
let io = require('./io');

module.exports = (passport) => {

  // Local Strategy login
  passport.use('local-login', 
  new LocalStrategy((username, password, done) => {
    console.log('username');
    // Match Username
    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?';
    db.query(sql, [username]).then(results => {
      if (!results.length) {
        return done(null, false, {
          type: 'loginMessage',
          message: 'Wrong Login',
        });
      }
      console.log('password');
      //  Match Password
      bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (isMatch) {
          console.log('Password is correct');
          return done(null, results[0]);
        } else {
          return done(null, false, {
            type: 'loginMessage',
            message: 'Wrong Login',
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }));

  // =========================================================================
  // passport session setup ==================================================
  // =========================================================================

  // used to serialize the user for the session
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log(user.username + ' has been Serialized');
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id]).then(results => {
      console.log(results[0].username + ' has been deserialized');
      done(results[0]);
    });
  });
};
```

This seems to go off without a hitch, now here is my login redirect:

```
// Login Process
router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/game',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true,
  }), (req, res) => {
    console.log('login route test');
  });
```

Again this seems to be doing well, it does in fact redirect me as intended. Now, here is some extra stuff I think might be causing it:

```
// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});
```

Then the game route:

```
//Route to game app
app.get('/game', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Log before it checks req.user');
  if (req.user) {
    console.log('req.user is working');
    res.render('game');
  } else {
    req.flash('error', 'You need to be signed in!');
    res.redirect('/');
  }
});
```

So here is the thing here: When I am not logged in and go to the `/game` route it will kick me back into my main route with the correct flash error. However, when I login, I can;t for the life of me get it to fire off a `console.log()` function. So I am thinking it is getting stuck with the `req.user` on login, but I am not sure why nor how. If more information is needed, I can give more... but this is mostly what all handles the login process (except socket.io, but it doesn't even get to that point yet, and all my socket.io file does is send the data client side for easy updates).

I will keep trying my luck, but since I am new to promises, this may be the reason why, and if it is, I may not be so lucky.

EDIT: Well, I've changed everything back to a normal callback for my DB (which is what I had it before). Weirdly though, I am getting the same result, and I've no idea why. This project had been put on hold for months, but I hadn't touched anything until I changed all the DB stuff. So something must have broken before I even touched anything when I left this project it was working just fine. But I did change it back to the promise method, because I'd rather stick to this message.

EDIT: Also, I am getting a 500 internal server error on the browser console.

EDIT: Updated code and added console.logs in more places to see where this is hanging up, and I'm still not sure. So here is the logging sequence when I click the login button:

```
username
password
Password is correct
Bloodmorphed has been Serialized
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
[object Object]
Bloodmorphed has been deserialized
[object Object]
```

EDIT: So it seems like the login process is not working correctly. I am not sure why and I can't find a problem with anything I am doing. I have looked at multiple sources of how to set-up passport for MySQL and while some of them differ a tiny bit, they all seem to be the same where it matters. I do not know why this is happening and according to multiple sources of working logins, I am doing this right.

Answer (score 1):

I am, well... simply an idiot. I forgot when I changed to a promise system, I handle errors inside the query itself, so there was no reason for me to pass it through.

so where I had done `done(results[0])` in the `passport.deserializeUser...` I just had to add null before it like so: `done(null, results[0])` so much wasted time on a simple matter. I feel like a dumby.